# При клике div-элемент должен перемещатся к координатам клика. Перемещается, но на отдалении - впечетление, что перепис координаты x и y. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

```js
let ball = document.getElementById('ball')
let field = document.getElementById('field')
field.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  ball.style.transform = `translateY(${e.clientY - 20}px)`;
  ball.style.transform += `translateX(${e.clientX - 20}px)`;
})
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 50px;
}

#field {
  height: 330px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

#ball {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: greenyellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: сделай [mcve] который можно запустить. как минимум не хватает пробела в строке, которая добавляется в `+=`

Comment: Уже делал минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Все работает нормально. Насколько я понимаю, то что-то влияет на координаты к которым div должен перемещаться. Не могу понять что может влиять.

Comment: в текущем вопросе воспроизводимого примера нет. есть только кусок кода, с ошибкой при составлении `transform`, причем неизвестно - ошибка ли это при переносе в вопрос либо в основном коде тоже она. Соответственно невозможно узнать единственная ли это ошибка

Comment: Ниже минимальный код:

Comment: ```<div id="field"><div id="ball"></div></div>```

Comment: ```let ball = document.getElementById('ball')
let field= document.getElementById('field')
field.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  ball.style.transform = `translateY(${e.clientY - 20}px)`;
  ball.style.transform += `translateX(${e.clientX - 20}px)`; 
})```

Comment: ````body{
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:50px;
}

#field{
    height: 330px; 
    width: 600px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative; 
} 

#ball{
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: greenyellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}```

Comment: Добавь это все непосредственно в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: Поправил - полный код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX) - глобальная координата.

[`translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate)- сдвигает относительно текущего положения.

Чтобы все работало корректно, нужно либо менять непосредственно `top` и `left`,

либо вычислять правильное смещение для `transform`

---

Для плавного перемещения, можно воспользоваться [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition):

```
      transition: left .5s ease, top .5s ease;
```

```js
let ball = document.getElementById('ball')
let field = document.getElementById('field')
field.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // добавляем поправку смещения контейнера, так как у него стоит `position: relative`
  ball.style.top = `${e.clientY - field.offsetTop}px`;
  ball.style.left = `${e.clientX - field.offsetLeft}px`;
})
```

```css
body {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 50px;
}

#field {
  height: 330px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

#ball {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: greenyellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: left .5s ease, top .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Все работает. Еще просьба - а как сделать, чтобы мяч не перескакивал, а котился?

Comment: @Dima, добавил пример, для плавного изменения. Либо альтернативный вариант, делать все то же самое только вручную

Comment: Премного благодарен!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!